# XOR register,register (assembler)

Tags: assembly, xor, x86

From time to time we have to analyze pieces of assembler code (IA32), 
and more than often i come across an instruction that looks like this:

```
xor ax, ax
```

or with other registers aswell: `xor dx, dx`, `xor al, al`, ...

What exactly does this do ? (ax xor ax always gives 0 ?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/which-is-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and (xor is the best way)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a common assembler idiom to set a register to 0.

`xor ax, ax` corresponds to `ax =  ax ^ ax` which, as you already noticed, is effectively `ax = 0`.

If I recall correctly the main advantage is that its code-size is smaller than `mov ax, 0`

Comment: Thanks, i imagined it had to be something different than setting it to 0 since i would use `mov ax, 0` for that but if it produces a shorter code-size it makes more sense indeed.

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly what it does -- zero the contents of a register

Answer (score 2):

xor %ax, %ax, as stated in earlier comments corresponds to ax = ax xor ax. This essentially set ax = 0. In addition, it also affects/modifies some of the EFLAGS such as OF, CF, SF, PF or ZF. In this case, PF and ZF flags will be set.

SF -  Indicates whether the result of the last operation resulted in a value whose most significant bit is set to 1.

PF -  Indicates if the number of set bits is odd or even in the binary representation of the result of the last operation.

ZF -  It is set if the result of the mathematical/logical operation is zero or reset otherwise.

Example is shown below using GDB snippets.

Instruction: xor    %ax,%ax

Before "xor"

```
(gdb) info registers
eax            0xaa55   43605
ecx            0x0  0
edx            0x80 128
ebx            0x0  0
esp            0x6f20   0x6f20
ebp            0x0  0x0
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x7c02   0x7c02
eflags         0x2  [ ]
cs             0x0  0
ss             0x0  0
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
```

After "xor"

```
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x0  0          --------------------> AX = 0          
ecx            0x0  0
edx            0x80 128
ebx            0x0  0
esp            0x6f20   0x6f20
ebp            0x0  0x0
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x7c04   0x7c04
eflags         0x46 [ PF ZF ] --------------------> Flags Set
cs             0x0  0
ss             0x0  0
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This answer is more detailed than is useful, IMO.  You don't need to explain how all the flags work in answer to a question about a zeroing idiom.  It would be enough to leave a comment pointing out that unlike `mov reg, 0`, xor affects the flags.  Since your answer popped this question onto the recent-activity front page, I ended up leaving a comment to a question with a link to a much more detailed answer about why xor is the best way to zero regs.  (Where I mentioned that in most cases, do the zeroing before the instruction whose flag-results you want.)

Comment: Thanks.. I agree it has more detail than needed. I noticing it now.