# xor ax, ax when loading segment register

Tags: assembly, operating-system, bootloader, x86

I'm trying to write a boot loader, and all the code I am writing is being run in real mode. In all the examples I find there is either an `xor ax, ax` or `xor eax, eax`, and I don't understand what this is doing. It seems to have something to do with setting up the segment registers, but I am unclear as to what.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201676/xor-register-register-assembler?rq=1

Comment: AX and EAX are not segment registers. Segment registers are registers ending with s like GS, FS, DS, ES...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xor instruction is Exclusive OR

Check out the exclusive OR truth table [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

```
xor eax, eax ; Set eax to 0
mov eax, 0   ; Set eax to 0
```

I'm not 100% sure about, but i think the XOR is used because of some historical reason.

Comment: I am not a smart man

Comment: Well, it's not always easy to see the problem if it is to easy to see ;)

Comment: XORing a register with itself to set it to zero was a fairly common optimization on 8-bit processors as it was usually a single-byte instruction.  It often took less space and executed faster than an immediate load with 0 which took two bytes.

Comment: @MartinJames: It's still the shortest and fastest way to zero a register on x86/x86-64. It requires no immediate (->short) and is special-cased on new processors to use very few execution resources while breaking dependency chains. It's useful.

Comment: @EOF TIL something. Orite :)

Comment: xor has many usages like toggling bit, parity check, checksum calculation... It isn't there for historical reasons.

Comment: xor is used because it's shorter and CPUs recognized that as a special case of setting to 0. There are some more reasons addressed in the other duplicated questions

Answer (score 3):

`xor ax, ax`  would do the same as `mov ax, 0`, but with additional capability of setting the flag to zero and clearing carry according to the logic of xor. And `xor` consumes less clocks than `mov` does in some old architectures.

`mov eax,eax` would take up 5 bytes in byte code where `xor eax,eax` would consume 2 bytes.

Comment: There's already a canonical answer about why `xor`-zeroing is better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and.  `xor` is still faster on modern Intel CPUs, even apart from code-size.  It's not just a historical / old architecture thing.  (On AMD CPUs, it's just a code-size advantage, but it's not slower so compilers use it.)